# Snapshots failing with --watchAll=true, but not --watchAll=false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, snapshot

I'm using jest to run unit testing on a large react project.  Many tests are snapshot tests which make sure the component renders the same every time and that every render matches the snapshot.

I noticed that our test script, which is just `react-scripts test` is failing, with a handful of failing snapshots since someone made some changes.  However, the script we use for CI/CD is `react-scripts test -u --watchAll=false`, so that the test suite will exit on completion and continue the CI/CD process.  With the `--watchAll-false` tag, I dont see any failing snapshots.

Why would that be?  What effect does `--watchAll` have on snapshot testing?  I can't seem to find any documentation on the relationship between the two.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I am facing it too. Running jest test without --watchAll=false --> snapshot passes. But running jest test with watchAll=false --> snapshot fails. Im using styled-components and jest-styled-components. snapshot failed because of class attribute naming difference, one has "sc"  appended to class attribute and one doesnt.

Comment: I never did figure this out.  I'm not sure how the dynamic class naming of styled-components would affect the consistency of rendering, but I have a similar situation with material ui.  I still don't know why watchAll has an affect on this.  LMK if you figure something out!

Comment: **update. It was the problem with my yarn and node. Had to reinstall node and yarn and it now both commands return same snapshots. Now it matches with tests run on CI